# URL to compose email in the new Inbox by Gmail

Tags: gmail, inbox

I'm a big fan of being one click (bookmarks bar link) away from composing a Gmail email. Now that things have moved over to Inbox by Gmail, the link no longer works.

I used to use this url https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#compose and I actually just figured out that I can hack the old link to still work with this link https://mail.google.com/mail/?ibxr=0#compose

Anyone know what the new proper link is for Inbox?

Comment: Questions about using web applications are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with "https://inbox.google.com/?mailto=mailto%3A" or with an address at the end if you use something like Alfred to dynamically fill a value "https://inbox.google.com/?mailto=mailto%3Aexample@website.com"

Answer (score 2):

The Inbox compose URL allows to specify the **to**, **cc**, **bcc**, **subject** and **body** query parameters. None of them is mandatory. An invalid field will be ignored, but no error will be raised.

See the url below for a complete example:

```
https://inbox.google.com/?to={to}&cc={cc}&bcc={bcc}&subject={subject}&body={body}
```

*PS: On a side note, this could be useful to configure Inbox as the **default email client** for Safari on macOS. See [this response](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320204/how-to-set-inbox-by-gmail-as-the-default-email-client-in-safari-macos) for more details.*